# How to retrieve data using single value in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my firebase database details: 
[image: this is my firebase database details]

Everywhere I have found, they get all details to  list view. But here I want to get all details using single value. For example: I want to get user's city, address, and dob based on their first name and print it in plain text. So not all person details at once, only for a single person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the single value then, you should use the row key like this,

```
val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference?.child("Users")?.child("{that row key}")
```

Or if you want to get the first item in that list you can use `limitToFirst` api like this,

```
val query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference?.child("Users")?.limitToFirst(1)
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Muthukrishnan Rajendran.here row key mean 8Wwzzry5rmQaCafR8goZtLbAuqC2 or user first name

Comment: 8Wwzzry5rmQaCafR8goZtLbAuqC2 - this is ket for that object

Comment: Ok, then i have another problem, think there are few users in user field.then i want to load that all users names in the drop down list,how do it. Actually i want to do that things.

Comment: @GaganaLakruwan, If my answer solved your problem which you asked, you can mark that as the answer.  
"i have another problem, think there are few users in user field.then i want to load that all users names in the drop down list,how do it" - I think you can create new question for that.